# Moving average python

Tags: python, moving-average

MatLab has the smoothdata function for calculating moving averages. At the edges it simply shortens the sample window and takes the average over the data available. I'm trying to find the moving average of a timeseries in python, convolution with a rectangular window yields NANs at the start and end, how can I get around this? I don't want to pad with zeros.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones(20) * 10

window = np.ones(3)

average = np.convolve(arr, window, mode='same') / len(window)
```

This is an array of 20 entries all of which are 10, the moving average window is 3. I want the window to become shorter at the edges so I keep a moving average of of 20 length but don't suffer edge effects.

Comment: df.dropna()?

Please show code that you have tried.

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how did it end? How different it was from your expectations?

Comment: I've edited the original post